# how to get this grouped result using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class Foo as follows.

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }   
}
```

I have a collection of this class let's say List and sometimes  I have data as follows in collection.

```
 Name           Value   
Jimmy           hello   
Jimmy           World   
Peter           how  
Peter           are you?   
Suzanne         I am fine
```

I want to combine the value field for same Names as folows

```
Name            Value  
Jimmy           hello World  
Peter           how are you?  
Suzanne         I am fine
```

Is there anyway this could be accomplished using Linq?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the Linq `GroupBy` as follows:

```
fooCollection.GroupBy(foo => foo.Name)

    // create a new "Foo" object based on each grouping
    .Select(g => new Foo() { 

        // "Name" becomes the group key (ie, "Jimmy", "Peter", etc)
        Name = g.Key, 

        // "Value" becomes the Value for all Foo in this group, concatenated
        Value = string.Join(" ", g.Select(item => item.Value).ToArray()) 
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Getting following error: The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments. Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'

Comment: @palmsnow should be corrected now -- I just added `.ToArray()` after `g.Select(item => item.Value)`

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like some kind of chat functionality. All other answers are good for a regular use and will work for sample case that you have provided, but I believe you'll need to do consecutive grouping.

Let's say that you have the data like this:

```
Name Value
Jimmy hello
Jimmy world
Peter how
Peter are you?
Suzanne I am fine
Jimmy OK, bye
```

Notice another Jimmy value at the bottom. If you use just the regular grouping as others have suggested, the result would be:

```
Name Value
Jimmy hello world OK, bye
Peter how are you?
Suzanne I am fine
```

You'll probably want something like this instead:

```
Name Value
Jimmy hello world
Peter how are you?
Suzanne I am fine 
Jimmy OK, bye
```

Take a look at this SO question for ideas on how to do consecutive grouping: [How to separate all consecutive Objects using Linq (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100375/how-to-separate-all-consecutive-objects-using-linq-c)

Answer (score 0):

```
from a in myList
group a by a.Name
into g
select new Foo {
                 Name = g.Key.Name,
                 Value = string.Join(" ",g.Select(x=>x.Value).ToArray()
               };
```